# View messed up since Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios

I had this app which I uploaded to the app store. 2 months later I'm having this bug, I didn't change anything in the app. Could it be a Xcode problem?

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't specific enough. You might not have changed any code but by using Xcode 7.1 you've started using a newer set of platform tools (iOS 9.1) and its likely that the way you've developed your app has not worked as you are expecting it to with the new platform tools. Update your question with more details on your approach including code snippets where relevant and somebody might be able to help.

Comment: You might want to look at my own question over here http://stackoverflow.com/q/33068342/1396265 - if it applies, you may see a way to fix it by adjusting locations and anchor points

Answer (score 0):

Might be your app would be working as you were using before. But you would not have applied the autolayout and sizeclasses to your app. Which xCode did you used before?

Comment: I think it was Xcode 7.0 and the app was ready for iOS 9. And we didn't change anything in the app